# Doubt in “C'est … et s'appelle …” sentence construction

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, coordination

If I want to say, "It is a special meal and is called Kheer" then is this the correct way to write it in French?

> C'est un repas spécial et s'appelle « Kheer ».

The problem that I am facing is that the verb is "too far away" from the subject. 
I've not come across any particular topic in my workbook that deals with this issue, so I really do not know what to even search for on the Internet.

Comment: The big problem here is that *être* only takes *ce* as a subject clitic when it's a copula, while *s'appeler* only takes *il*, *elle* or *ça*. That means *ce* can't have scope over both verbs even in formal French. While you can rejigger the sentence to fix it, the simplest way is simply to add the correct clitic to *s'appeler*: c'est un repas spécial et il s'appele "Kheer". That sentence is still awkward, but it's grammatical.

Comment: C'est un repas spéciale qui s'appelle "Kheer".

Comment: @Eauquidort On aimerait lire une telle réponse. Merci !

Answer (score 4):

On peut utiliser différentes formules :

- C'est un repas spécial, *on l*'appelle "Kheer".
- C'est un repas spécial *qui s*'appelle "Kheer".
- C'est un repas spécial *appelé* "Kheer".
- On appelle *ce* repas "Kheer".

*Repas* ne convient pas tout à fait, il est d'usage de préciser :

> - S'il s'agit d'une seule recette : *C'est un* plat *spécial ...* ou *C'est une* recette *spéciale...*
> - S'il s'agit de tout un repas :  *C'est un* menu *spécial ...*

Comment: Intéressant ! Je n'avais jamais fait la distinction entre *repas* et *plat*, mais à bien y penser, *repas* désigne davantage le moment où l'on mange un *plat* ou de la nourriture. Donc *repas* à la signification de *moment où l'on mange*.

Comment: @cram2208 -- Si j'en crois le petit Robert, c'est la somme des deux :  *Repas* 1°) Nourriture, ensemble d'aliments divers, de mets et de boissons pris en une fois, à heures réglées... 2°) Action de se nourrir, répétée quotidiennement à heure réglées, et plus ou moins conforme aux usages imposés par la société...

Answer (score 0):

La construction est limite et sonne faux. En effet: le sujet *C* de est un repas spécial est un raccourci de *ça*, *ceci* ou *cela*. On a du mal à le raccrocher au bout de la phrase.

**Préférer:**

> Ceci est un repas spécial et qui s'appelle "Kheer".
>
> Ceci est un repas spécial et il s'appelle "Kheer".
>
> Ceci est un repas spécial et s'appelle "Kheer".

Comment: Pas certain que *Ceci ... et ...* sonne tout à fait mieux, c'est un peu 'laborieux' et cela ressemble à une démonstration commerciale. Dans un autre contexte il serait beaucoup plus difficile à placer, surtout à l'oral ou le *et* peut être facilement supprimé : "Qu'est-ce que c'est ? -- C'est une repas spécial qu'on appelle Kheer" ; dans ce cas, utiliser *ceci + et* pourrait donner une touche pédante, ou un peu 'appliquée' (genre : bon élève qui répond en récitant sa leçon)... mais ce n'est peut-être qu'une impression personnelle :)

Answer (score 0):

> (1) C'est un mets particulier que l'on nomme/appelle « Kheer ».
>  (2) C'est
>   un plat particulier qu'on désigne sous le nom de « Kheer ».
> (3) C'est
>   du/un « Kheer », un mets plutôt commun s'apparentant à une
>   crème-dessert (pouding) au riz mais auquel la préparation en tant que
>   *prasād* (offrande) pourrait conférer une importance particulière en Inde. 
>   (4) Le « Kheer » est un repas spécial servi lors du [name of the
>   event]. (metonymic)
>  (5) Le « Kheer » est le plat par excellence
>   lors du [name of the event].
>  (6) C'est un repas spécial et ça
>   s'appelle un « Kheer ».

*Son nom est dérivé du terme sanskrit ksheera (क्षीर) qui signifie en français « lait »*. ([Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kheer))

---

A [comment](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/18661/doubt-in-cest-et-sappelle-sentence-construction#comment35361_18661) provides analysis for the problem you were facing and you just needed to abstract your "too far away" idea into that of the *repetition of the pronoun* in the context of *coordination*. But the focus of this answer is lexicon and considering the subject matter, it is not clear whether you meant a *dish* or the meal in the context of a *specific purpose* so it may indeed be *un repas spécial* (4, 5).

I reject forthwith any construction with the relative *qui* or the pronoun *il* in context; the former feels anthropomorphic to my ears, while the impersonal construction with *il* feels needlessly remote and unusual. I provide an example (6) with the *démonstratif* ça(cela) which I consider colloquial but which still allows for neutrality, yet the sentence remains imprecise imho for the aforementioned reasons (dish vs. special purpose).